# Facebook PHP SDK, server-side login, without clicking any link (knowing password).

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Can i log in to my Facebook account (Knowing user id and password), in the server using Facebook php-sdk, and without need to click any URL?
If yes, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is against Facebook's Terms of Service to use a user's email address and password to login to their account. You should instead use the Facebook API to achieve this, but it requires manual login by a user.

There are ways of achieving automatic login using credentials, but since it's not allowed, I won't go into detail. Facebook also detects and prevents most of the common method of auto-login.